# Download a file from S3 - Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to download files from amazon s3, and the code here works for files like docx, pdf etc... But for images, it just open a new tab, and shows the image there, no download started.

```
function downloadLink($docpath)
{
    $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');

    return $s3->url($docpath);
}
```

I replaced the url method with download, but that dont work at all, it says err 404 page not found.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The browser behaves that way by default, but you can force it to start a download by adding the following HTTP headers in the response from the server:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="example.png"
```

Comment: You're right. Then you have to deliver the file with octet-stream then it should work to download the file. Or when it's a download for someone make a ZIP-file.

Comment: Thats the only way to do it? i must confess im not familiar with js or ajax
There is nothing on the method i can do to force the download^of the images? Becouse the other files work fine

Comment: It's not about javascript, check out the PHP function 'header()' or read about HTTP responses in Laravel here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses

Comment: return response($s3->url($docpath))->header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachement; filename="example.png"');
Something like this from what i read from laravel docs.. however it doesnt work

Comment: I think what your original code snippet actually did, was redirecting the user to the S3 URL. If so, try adding the headers in the S3 management console. (In that case the headers of the relevant response stem from S3, not from your Laravel project.)